object-fit: cover для блока
Описание
Один из моих недавных вопросов был про поведения элемента схожего с object-fit: contain, только не для картинки, а для блока.
Теперь в такой же ситуации я пытаюсь добиться поведения схожего с object-fit: cover.
Вопрос
Возможно ли такое, способ без костылей?
Ну... конечный вариант, есть способ с костылями?

если правильно понял, берёте тот самый ответ от @UModeL и меняете там у div#child - MaX-height: 100% на MiN-height: 100%. и всё. можете в том же сниппете инспектором поменять свойство для наглядности.

@puffleeck и вправду . Оставьте ваше решение как ответ.
